# Компилятор ругается(checked), когда я создаю объект, для которого я указываю дженерик

Tags: java, объекты, generics

Пишу свой ArrayList.

Имеется класс `Test` (для тестирования) и класс `ArrayListMy`. Раньше они оба находились в папке src. Сейчас же я их перенёс в разные папки: src(Test, Package(ArrayListMy)). Теперь компилятор просто в ярости и отказывается принимать запись вида:

```java
ArraylistMy<Integer> a = new ArrayListMy<>();
```

Вот мои классы:

```java
import Package.ArrayListMy;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


///////        ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА       ///////

        ArrayListMy<Integer> arrayListMy = new ArrayListMy<Integer>();

///////////////////////////////////////////


        arrayListMy.add(0);
        arrayListMy.add(1);
        arrayListMy.add(2);
        arrayListMy.add(3);
        arrayListMy.add(2);
        arrayListMy.add(2);
        arrayListMy.add(2);
        arrayListMy.add(2);

        System.out.println(arrayListMy.get(1));
    }
}
```

```java
package Package;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayListMy <T>{
    private Object[] array;
    private int size;
    private int index = 0;

    public ArrayListMy() {
        array = new Object[0];
        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean add(T o){
        if(array.length == size){
            if(array.length == 0){
                array = new Object[1];
            } else{
                increaseArray();
            }
        }

        array[index] = o;

        size++;
        index++;

        return true;
    }

    public T get(int i){
        return find(i);
    }

    public boolean remove(int i){


        size--;
        index--;

    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T find(int i){
        if (i >= 0 && i <= array.length)
        {
            return (T) array[i];
        }else
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }


    private void increaseArray(){
        Object[] temp;
        temp = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1 + array.length / 2);

        array = temp;
    }
}
```

P.S. Класс `ArrayListMy` не дописан.

**ВЕРСИЯ JDK - 8**

Comment: 1. Какую ошибку выдаёт компилятор? 2. `i >= 0 && i <= array.length` надо заменить на `i >= 0 && i < array.length`

Comment: хм..... Вот сейчас я совершенно озадачен, дело в том что я пишу в IntelliJ IDEA, и он мне подчёркивает всю строку красным, с пометкой Incompatible types. Но дело к компиляции у меня не доходило (Зечем если IDE говорит что это не верно) Вот сейчас я скомпилировал и оно прекрасно работает. Но IDE до сих пор ругаеться

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код должен работать

Единственные рекомендации которые могу дать, попробуйте рестартанут IDEA

ps, так же именуйте пакеты с маленькой буквы (JNC)

pps, метод ArrayListMy#remove() должен возвращать return, который у вас пропущен

```
public boolean remove(int i){
    size--;
    index--;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле не понятная "дичь" твориться с моим IDE :) Рестарт не помог(
За remove я вкурсе, просто не дописал ещё

Comment: только что решил проблему, IDE не нравилось имя пакета с большой буквы